# What kind of action is an active Perception roll?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

There's this popular treatise on what it means to be hidden called [The Rules Of Hidden Club](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2739081) posted on the WotC boards.
It's widely regarded as a good and toroughful explanation on what being hidden means, how to achieve the condition and how not to lose it, and it looks like the author made a great effort to be sure his grasp on the rules he was explaining was solid.
To date, whenever there's a discussion on this site or in a forum I usually write in, you can be sure this article gets linked. I trust this to be a good indicator of the usefulness of said explanation.

The Fifth Rule states: "An enemy can spend a Minor Action to roll Perception"

Page 186 of PHB states that actively rolling perception is a standard action.

You can see for yourself how those sentences are apparently incompatible. **What happened?**
Is there some difference between PCs and NPCs?
Was there some *Updates and Errata* or some later manual changed how it works?
Is it just an error by LordOfWeasels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The active usage of the Perception skill, like the rest of the overall of the Hidden-related skills, was changed to only be a minor action in Players Handbook 2 (pg. 223). This is repeated in the Rules Compendium, page 150.